# When does the campaign in Warhammer 3rd edition start?

Tags: lore, campaign-settings, wfrp-2e, wfrp-3e

I'm playing WFRP 2nd edition but our campaign started a bit later that default 2525 IC.

I want to know if there is any additional information about world events in WRFP 3rd edition that can influence our campaign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WFRP 2e Setting starts in 2522-2523. Specifically, the Storm of Chaos outlined in WFRP 2e states the war end, with the armies of Archaon, The Lord of the End Times, in full retreat from Middenheim at the beginning of 2523[1].

WFRP 3e resets the clock well forward of the Storm of Chaos, specifically near the end of the WFRP 1e (yes, the original) *The Enemy Within* campaign, near the end of *Something's Rotten on Kislev*[2][3].

***The Enemy Within*(1E) specifically starts in year 2512.** This is stated in the module and the calendar for that year is provided. This puts the Storm of Chaos a full decade later. *Something Rotten in Kislev* and *Empire in Flames* (or *Empire in War*, depending on the transitional narrative the GM wishes to offer) compress this time line a bit with a common sense narrative of travel in the Old World. The events in *Empire at War* for instance are scaled almost a full two, in-setting, years; it just takes that long to travel the distances and account for encounters. I can't speak for *The Enemy Within* being a decade in scale, but it is possible.

1. *Darkness Rising* : *The Complete History of the Storm of Chaos*, Games Workshop Limited, 2005 *NB: I too play my campaign in the years following the Storm of Chaos, allows for a looser interpretation of the setting canon, without creating problems for players that research the setting.*
2. "The scenario was built from scratch, using the various plot threads
   from *The Enemy Within* series up to *Something Rotten in Kislev*. My
   intent was to provide a more appropriate ending to this
   well-regarded campaign that ties the first edition WFRP to the
   Warhammer of the second edition. The scenario used first edition
   mechanics and was developed with the help of a small group of
   friends." Alfred Nuñez, Jr. speaking about his *Empire at War*, a scenario for the end of *The Enemy Within* campaign.
3. http://youtu.be/GKjdIX9J98s, Jay Little, Sr. RPG Designer for FFG at GenCon 2009 speaking about the setting for WFRP 3e.

**If you want more about the setting, considering watching the series of Jay Little at GenCon 2009 and look for *Darkness Rising* on eBay.**

Comment: If I understand right - WFRP 3ED goes back in timeline making that stuff in WFRP 2ED didn't happen yet :O ?

Comment: That is correct. It's a reset. I should point out that the material of WFRP 2E is still very rich and directly applicable to 3E, for the most part. Specifics in the political makeup of the canon might be tenuous, but manageable.

Comment: Additionally, I have confirmed that the WFRP 3E _The Enemy Within_--same name as the acclaimed original _TEW_ of WFRP 1E, but different story--release brings the timeline of WFRP 3E into the Storm of Chaos as presented in 2E (though in 2E the Storm of Chaos is over and all that is left is scorched earth, retreating armies and refugees). The Storm of Chaos, if you did not know, was a Warhammer Fantasy **Battle** Campaign played worldwide with results fed into a story narrative that later became _Darkness Rising_ : _The Complete History of the Storm of Chaos_.

Comment: They messed it all up in my opinion... thanks  @javafueled !